# Exception Handling : But do not end up in the catch block

Tags: c++, exception

I'm getting a unhandled exception in a function. The function is called many times.

```
try {
  unsigned char* b1 = new unsigned char[Length];  //<---here
  unsigned char* b2 = new unsigned char[Length];
  //do some stuff which doesn't seem to throw an exception...then at the end
  delete[] b1;
  delete[] b2;
}
catch (...)
{
    cout<< "Error..." <<end;
 }
```

Thing is, the unhandled exception occurs at nearly random times. It breaks on the first statement. And the other issue is: why isn't this caught? Visual Studio halts and I'm in new.cpp.

And my third question/issue is: How can I track down the problem? The Length is never some uninitialized amount; usually around 512.

Comment: What exception is thrown or is actually an error and not an exception?

Comment: you could use debugger and break on throw, then examine where exactly exception is thrown, the variable values etc..

Comment: Go to `Debug -> Exceptions` in VS and select `C++ Exceptions` and then run the program in the debugger. You'll break when and where an exception is thrown.

Comment: The catch statement will only catch C++ exceptions.  Very high odds that you are actually getting an access violation, exception code 0xc0000005.  That's a major kaboom, show is over.  You'll need to fix the heap corruption problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like cout << ... requires some memory allocation, but it cannot do it. Configure debugger to break execution when exception is thrown (as other people suggest) and see what is thrown and at what point.
BTW, Sutter writes that you probably shouldn't try to catch memory allocation exceptions at all - it's quite hard to do needed error reporting without any memory allocations, and these are very likely to fail, so why bother. (And maybe you will not get these exceptions at all - virtual memory & swapping are such wonderful things...)

Comment: The app breaks on this line after about 46 iterations: called in new.cpp (not part of my code):

void *__CRTDECL operator new(size_t size) _THROW1(_STD bad_alloc)
        {       // try to allocate size bytes
        void *p;
        while ((p = malloc(size)) == 0) ///<<<<----HERE
                if (_callnewh(size) == 0)
                {       // report no memory
                static const std::bad_alloc nomem;
                _RAISE(nomem);
                }

        return (p);
        }
I enabled all the exceptions. size here = 512.
How do I figure out what's causing bad allocation?

Comment: Bad allocation just after 46*2 allocations of 512 bytes? What is your compiler?

Comment: Visual Studio VC++ Express 2010. ....The app called a large number of procedures many of which allocate memory, etc. I'm reducing that to just one (at a time), so see if that helps me find the bad actor. Yes, after 512 bytes.